# Entire function $f(\frac{1}{p})=\frac{1}{1+p}$ for all prime $p$.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I'm working on this problem

"Find all entire functions $f(\frac{1}{p})=\frac{1}{1+p}$ for all prime $p$."

My approach is using identity theorem. But in this case it does not seem good. We have $$f(1/p)=\frac{1/p}{1+1/p}$$
So naturally, I set $g(z)=f(z)-\frac{z}{z+1}$. Consider the plane excluded a circle around $z=-1$. Then $g$ is analytic in that region. And $g=0$ on the set of $\{1/p\}$ which has a limit point. So $g=0$ on the constructed given. But how do I extend it to $-1$? Or I can't?

Comment: You have shown that there is only function, $z/(1+z)$, analytic at $0$ and such that $f(a_n)=1/(1+1/a_n)$ for some decreasing sequence $a_n\to 0$. If $f$ is analytic on a larger domain then it has to be the analytic continuation of $z/(1+z)$.

Comment: i don't quite understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: what is an entire function extending $z/(1+z)$?

Comment: $z/(1+z)$ is meromorphic on the whole complex plane, analytic on $\Bbb{C}-\{-1\}$, that's the best extension.

Comment: so this is where I conclude there is no such entire function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such entire function $f$. Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\dfrac z{z+1}.\end{array}$$Then, for each prime $p$, $f\left(\frac1p\right)=g\left(\frac1p\right)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic, since $\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$ is connected and since $\{z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}\mid f(z)=g(z)\}$ has an accumulation point ($0$), the identity theorem implies that$$(\forall z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}):f(z)=g(z).$$But that's impossible, since $\lim_{z\to-1}f(z)=f(-1)$, whereas the limit $\lim_{z\to-1}g(z)$ doesn't exist in $\Bbb C$.